# Fullcalendar allDay is always true

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

No matter where the event is dropped, allDay returns true

checking if allDay is true or false:

```
eventDrop: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
  if (allDay) {
    alert("Event is now all-day");
  } else {
    alert("Event has a time-of-day");
  }
}
```

the test event:

```
{
  title: 'TEST',
  start: '2017-05-04T00:00:00',
  allDay: false
}
```

video that shows the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1-avkl977s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs the parameters are `function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ),` and the `event` object is the one that holds the `allDay` property.
So your function parameters and your `if` statement are wrong:
You should change the function parameters to `function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view )` and the if statement to:

```
if(event.allDay)
```